How to calculate the summation $\sum^{\infty}_{n=r}\frac{A^n} { 2n+1 }$
How to calculate the summation $\sum^{\infty}_{n=r}\frac{A^n} {   2n+1 }$?
For the following summation with lower limit set to zero as shown below,
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{A^n} {   2n+1 }$$
I derived the solution that is to be,
$$\frac{1}{A}\log \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{A}}{1-\sqrt{A}}\right).$$
However, for $n=r$, how do I modify my answer?
My attempt at it is that the solution is modified as follows,
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=r}\left[\frac{1}{A}\log \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{A}}{1-\sqrt{A}}\right) - \frac{A^r} { 2r+1 }\right].$$
where $|A|<1$

Your last attempt gives a divergent sum since the terms do not tend to zero. Your original sum is the tail of the series with $r=0$ and there is no simple closed form for that. You can write it for instance as an integral though.

Also $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{A^n }}{{2n + 1}}}  = \frac{1}{{2\sqrt A }}\log \left( {\frac{{1 + \sqrt A }}{{1 - \sqrt A }}} \right).
$$

@Gary Thanks, I added the definition of A which makes the summation convergent if I am correct.

It doesn't. The terms do not depend on $n$ and there are infinitely many of them. Even if you replace $r$ by $n$, the log term is constant and you add up infinitely many copies of it. Subtracting $A^n/(2n+1) $ doesn't make much difference since it eventually becomes negligible.

And you didn't correct the log expression as I suggested in my comment above.

Have a look at my edit

The problem is not simple in terms of elementary functions for
$$S_r=\sum^{\infty}_{n=r}\frac{A^n} { 2n+1 }$$ A few expressions are
$$S_r=\frac{A^r }{2 r+1}\,\,
   _2F_1\left(1,r+\frac{1}{2};r+\frac{3}{2};A\right)$$ $$S_r==\frac{B_A\left(r+\frac{1}{2},0\right)}{2 \sqrt{A}}=\frac{1}{2} A^r\, \Phi \left(A,1,r+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ where appear the Gaussian hypergeomtric function,  the incomplete Euler beta function and the Lerch transcendent function.
Another solution, as @Gary commented, is to use the integral (assuming $A \leq 1$
$$T_r=\int^{\infty}_{r}\frac{A^n} { 2n+1 }\,dn=-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{A}}\text{Ei}\left(\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (A)\right)$$ where appears the  exponential integral function.
Since we know the integral), we could think about Euler-MacLaurin summation but, even in its simplest form, the result is really messy (I shall not print).
Assuming that $r$ is large
$$S_r\sim-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{A}}\text{Ei}\left(\left(r+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (A)\right)+$$ $$ A^r \left(\frac{\log ^7(A)-40 \log ^5(A)+1680 \log ^3(A)-100800 \log (A)+604800}{2419200  r}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)\right)$$
Edit
Using @Gary's comment
$$\frac{1}{{\sqrt A }}\int_0^{\sqrt A } {\frac{{t^{2r} }}{{1 - t^2 }}\,dt}=\frac{B_A\left(r+\frac{1}{2},0\right)}{2 \sqrt{A}}$$

By integral representation, I meant $\frac{1}{{\sqrt A }}\int_0^{\sqrt A } {\frac{{t^{2r} }}{{1 - t^2 }}{\rm d}t}$.

@Gary. This gives the same Euler beta function.

Sure. Did my answer to your recent question help?

@Gary. I am afraid that it makes the problem for difficult (at least to me). But thanks again

I like @Gary integral answer.
